# Excel 2003 file with Visual Basic is crashing Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have 2003 Excel file with Visual Basics code in it. It works fine in versions up through Excel 2010, but it does not work in Excel 2013. Excel crashes whenever VB functionality is used. I have Add-ins Analysis ToolPak - VBA. Under Trust Center I have checked "Trust access to the VBA Project model". Macros are enabled when file is open. Excel 4 Macrosheets and Add-in Files are checked.

Of course I do not want to rewrite the program. Any suggestions?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: When it crashes does it tell you any error messages? Anything in the logs?  When you step though the code, what command is it crashing on?

Comment: It might call processes that are no longer available in excel 2010. Unless you post the code, we cannot troubleshoot it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue opening Excel 2003 file with macros in Excel 2013.
Error message is "Excel has stopped working" once you try to open it even from the document recovery tool. I deleted the tabs having automatic refresh using macros from the initial file without modifying the macros code itself and I do not have the error anymore. But I lost the embedded intelligence within the file.